# Can Mung Bean Nuclease only digest a ssDNA 5' overhang?

Tags: enzymes, cloning, recombinant

Can Mung Bean Nuclease only digest a ssDNA 5' overhang, if the double-stranded region of DNA (20bp) is A-T rich at the ends?

Does this enzyme degrade 5' overhang (5bp or 30 bp) with 100% efficiency?